# Working with nested tables. Applying styles to cells of topmost table only

Tags: jquery, css

I have a page with nested tables. I need to be able to apply certain styles only to odd rows of the top level table and not to the tables within this table.

Not really sure hot to do that... I think with jQuery I can do something like this:

```
$(".topTable tr:odd td").addClass(".rowColor");
```

Comment: indeed you can. What's the question?

Comment: Why you need jquery for this. You can use http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild and http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthoftype - Read also http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/understandingnthchildexpressions

Comment: @Jawad, that is a good option, but it looks like it doesn't work at all in IE.

Comment: @santa As you can see, working with nested tables is not easy. You would be better off using DIVs instead of nested tables...

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over this. I made my recommendations. What is it about nesting tables that's messing things up?

Comment: @santa It's not easy and simple to select specific cells/rows with CSS (as you can see with your own issue)... For instance, `#topTable td` selects all cells, whether they're direct or nested... You could select only nested cells like so: `#topTable table td`, but selecting only direct cells is not so easy. This allegedly works: `#topTable > tbody > tr > td`

Comment: @Chriszuma: Works fine in IE9 - http://jsfiddle.net/U27ET/

Comment: @Jawad Read the question. The issue is with nested tables...

Comment: @Santa: Post the HTML please.

Comment: @Sime Vidas: Well done. You read the question!

Comment: @Jawad The OP wants the styles to apply only to the rows of the topmost table. The selector in your demo matches nested rows too.

Comment: @Sime Vidas: Lets say you want to style the label of a select element. So you do select[lable="my_label"]{color: red;}. The problem is the <option> will also be red, so you do option{color: black;} to negate the inhertiance. Similiar thing can be done here. So i have asked for the HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(".topTable > tbody > tr:odd").addClass("rowColor");
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/r5UgL/3/

but I recommend against nesting tables.

Answer (score 0):

You have only 1 mistake, remove the dot when adding your class. It should be:

```
$(".topTable tr:odd td").addClass("rowColor");
```

or apply the css to the tr:

```
$(".topTable tr:odd").addClass("rowColor");
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using jQuery to do this you are actually being a bit too specific, you really only need:

```
$('.topTable tr:odd').addClass('rowColor');
```

This is kind of nitpicky because your method would work, but it applies the class to every TD in odd TRs and really you only need to apply it once to the odd TRs.

However, you can also do this in straight CSS (Firefox 3.5+, Opera 9.5+, Chrome 2+, Safari 3.1+, IE 9+) with something like:

```
.topTable > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd){
    background-color:red;
}
```

example here: http://jsfiddle.net/DFwHL/7/

Comment: My nested test wasn't deep enough, fixed it now.

Comment: Your demo works now because you started using the child selector `>` instead of the descendant selector. That's the key here.